# Disable remote port forwarding through jump host

Tags: ssh

I have three servers, S1, S2 and S3. S2 is a bastion server and the only one I am in control of, S1 is a server in a protected network and S3 is a server accessible through the public internet. Users in S1 and S3 do not have shell access to S2. I want to allow a user in S1 to do local port forwarding to S3 but not remote port forwarding (so from S1 `ssh -J user@S2 -L <lport>:S3:<rport> user@S3` should work, but `ssh -J user@S2 -R <rport>:localhost:<lport> user@S3` should not work). What is the configuration I need in S2's sshd_config?

Answer (score 0):

`ssh -J S2 S3` on S1 is equivalent to connecting from S1 to S2 and then from S1 to S3 (using packets forwarded through S2). If you add `-L` and/or `-R` to the command, the tunnels will belong to the latter connection.

`sshd_config` of S2 is only relevant for the connection from S1 to S2. From the point of view of SSH server on S2, `-J` used on S1 is very similar to `-L` used on S1: it asks the server on S2 to establish a TCP connection to somewhere (S3 in your case) on demand. In general any data can be passed through such tunnel and the SSH server on S2 is not interested in inspecting it, it just passes the stream. Even if it knew the stream is another SSH connection (S1 talking to S3) and it wanted to censor it somehow, it couldn't; because it's a separate SSH connection with separate encryption. To censor this connection S2 would need to perform a man-in-the-middle attack. SSH (*Secure* Shell) is deliberately designed not to be vulnerable to attacks.

For the connection from S1 to S3 (using packets forwarded through S2) it's `sshd_config` of S3 that matters.

If a user (instead of using `-J`) chooses to connect from S1 to S2 and *then* from S2 to S3 by running `ssh` *on S2*, then he or she may try to establish a tunnel from S1 to S3 (or from S3 to S1) by chaining two `-L` tunnels: from S1 to S2 and from S2 to S3 (or two `-R` tunnels: from S3 to S2 and from S2 to S1). This would make S2 a *legitimate* man in the middle. In this case `sshd_config` of S2 is the right place to disallow tunnels from S1 to S2 (or from S2 to S1).

Suppose you could force users to connect this way. Allowing them to chain `-L` tunnels to reach arbitrary ports on S3 or beyond means they are able to create an SSH connection from S1 to S3 via tunnels. And if they can reach S3 this way then `-R` in such tunneled connection is a deal between S1 and S3 *only*.

Ask yourself if you should care. You control S2 only. In case of `ssh -J S2 S3` invoked on S1, the server under your control accepts the SSH connection to itself and establishes a connection to S3 (only to relay a bidirectional stream). If you want `ssh -J S2 S3` to work, you need these two functionalities. If the user uses `-L` and/or `-R`, your S2 will do *exactly the same thing*. S3 however will initiate connections (in case of `-L`) and/or start listening (in case of `-R`). Why should it be your concern? Let the admins of S3 handle it; they have the right tool, i.e. `sshd_config` on S3.